# check if table has been created in code first approach

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework's code-first approach to create tables, and I need to check if there are any entities in the database that I need to delete:

```
class MyDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyDocument> Documents { get; set; }
}


using (var data = new MyContext())
{
    var present = from d in data.Documents
                  where d.Id == "some id" || d.Id == "other id"
                  select d;
    // delete above documents
}
```

on first run, when there is no table yet, the LINQ expression above throws an exception:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Documents'
```

How do I check if the table is there and if it is not, then set `present` to the empty set, perhaps? Or maybe there is a way to force database/table creation before I issue the LINQ query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF will actually check the entire context against the DB it is attached to.
The DB can have more than the context. But not less.
So actually you check

```
 Context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

If the DB and context dont match and you are using automatic migrations, then you get specific object errors.  But this can be misleading in terms of the how EF is handling the context to DB comparison.

You could of course try and access every DBSet in a context
Not sure how useful that is though.

EF Code first supports Migrations, either Automated or on demand.

See [EF Code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621)

```
Database.SetInitializer
```

use `SetInitializer` command to turn on automatic migrations for example.

The link will provide more info on the Manual/controlled approach to db migration for advanced db handling.   The easier Automatic approach, is also described in the link.